# How to disable other table rows while one row is editing Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table which loads through php for each.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered saving automatically when focus is lost?  That way you wouldn't need the save/edit buttons.

Comment: Please post enough of your HTML that we can reproduce your problem more easily in order to help you.

Comment: @David Thomas I've added the html . pls check

Comment: Something like: `$(this).closest("tr").siblings().find("td.edit a").hide();` ?

Comment: Ok - quick re-read: your question is the *opposite* of the question's title.   Title: disable *other* rows (as per my comment above).  Question: person clicks 2nd, first becomes readonly.  Please determine what you actually want.

Comment: Off topic: `.live()` was deprecated in *2011*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to first disabled all inputs, then enable the one that was clicked :

```js
$("td.group-name input").on('click', function() {
     // disable all inputs
    $("td.group-name input").attr("readonly", true);
     // enable this input
    $(this).attr("readonly", false);
     // hide all 'Save'
    $('td.group-save').hide();
     // show this 'Save'
    $(this).parent().parent().find('td.group-save').show();
     // show all 'Edit'
    $('td.group-edit').show();
     // hide this 'Edit'
    $(this).parent().parent().find('td.group-edit').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="line-height: 20px;">
    <td class="group-name">
      <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" value="<?= $name[0] ?>" />
    </td>
    <td class="group-id" style="display: none;">
      <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" value="<?= $name[2] ?>" />
    </td>
    <td class="group-edit">
      <a href="#" class="edit" style="font-style: italic;">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group-save" style="display: none;">
      <a id="editName" href="#"style="font-style: italic;">Save</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a href="#" id="removeName" style="font-style: italic;">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="line-height: 20px;">
    <td class="group-name">
      <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" value="<?= $name[0] ?>" />
    </td>
    <td class="group-id" style="display: none;">
      <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" value="<?= $name[2] ?>" />
    </td>
    <td class="group-edit">
      <a href="#" class="edit" style="font-style: italic;">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group-save" style="display: none;">
      <a id="editName" href="#"style="font-style: italic;">Save</a>
    </td>
    <td class="group">
      <a href="#" id="removeName" style="font-style: italic;">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when I try to click on 2nd input , still the link next first input also having 'save' buton instead 'edit' any fix for that ?

Comment: I want to make other rows link as 'edit' and make focused input link as 'save'. so if they select next input. other ''save' should 'edit' and link relate to clicked input only should have 'save' link. please advice

Comment: @dil I updated my answer, it does exactly what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add a common class to all the inputs:

```
<input class="myInput">
```

Then you can make all the inputs readonly before you allow editing of the desired input:

```
$("td.group-name input").live('click', function() {
    $(".myInput").attr("readonly", true); // this makes all the inputs readonly
    $(this).attr("readonly", false); // and here you make your input writable
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.group-edit').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.group-save').show();
});
```

You can also write your own function (using that class), that resets state of all rows to "not being edited", and then call this function before making the row editable:

```
function resetEverything(){
    $(".myInput").each(function(key, row){
         $(row).find("td.group-name input").attr("readonly", false);
         $(row).find("td.group-edit").show();
         $(row).find("td.group-save").hide();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: when I try to click on 2nd input , still thelink next first input also having 'save' buton instead 'edit' any fix for that

Comment: Please see edited answer - the function I provided should help :)

Comment: do I need to call the function before   
First of all you should add a common class to all the inputs:

<input class="myInput">
Then you can make all the inputs readonly before you allow editing of the desired input:

$("td.group-name input").live('click', function() { fucntion ?

Comment: First you add the class - you can do it in PHP, then you can call the function in your click handler, before the `$(this).attr("readonly", false);` row.

Comment: still all rows getting change 'edit' to 'save' . I want to make one input and that row only have 'save' button. all others should 'edit' links. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, that jQuery function by its definition, `$("td.name input")`, will only catch the first `td`, as it's looking for the input of a `td` with a class of `name` only.

Second, `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on` instead, like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_live.asp)

Third, it would be wise to define a common class that ALL `td`'s could share, perhaps

`<td class"focusable">... </td>`

Once you have the clicked element selected, you could use a call to `.siblings()`. And then use the `each()` method to iterate through the array that `.siblings()` creates, turning off their readonly status. As such:

```
$("td.focusable").on('click', function() {
    var tds = $(this).siblings();
    tds.each(function(index, tdElement { 
      tdElement.first().attr("readonly", true) // ensures all td elements' input child element will be enabled to readonly
    });
    $(this).first().attr("readonly", false);
    // do your other work with this
});
```

Comment: when I try to click on 2nd input , still thelink next first input also having 'save' buton instead 'edit' any fix for that

Comment: i'm getting an error "tdElement.first is not a function"

Comment: oops, try `$(tdElement).first().attr("readonly", true)` instead